# Rides tracking app for windows phone

Tags: bikeroutes, maps, performance-tracking

What are some tracking apps for Windows phone which use OpenStreet Maps or Google Maps?
My location (Minsk, Belarus) is a white spot on HERE Nokia maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few apps that should be able to use open street map and record GPS tracks:

Simple OSM
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/simple-osm/9710865b-2c38-e011-854c-00237de2db9e

GPX Travel Map
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gpx-travel-map/13a79a34-c283-4f5c-b3fb-4d02e3f4f43a

Navi Computer
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/navicomputer/26425685-6381-4767-b3b8-bb0448c2cb69

Try searching the app store for 'OpenStreetMap' and there are many other options.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Phones + Open street map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Windows_Phone)

I know strava requires installation of the googlemaps app to function, but they don't make anything for windows. If you want to use their service of comparing against different users, you can upload data from another app as long as its the right format (which should be possible with any of those open street map apps for windows ).

Answer (score 2):

There are several that you can try, many of which are [listed here](https://strava.zendesk.com/entries/26589945). Should that link go down, here's the apps listed at that page:

- CycloMeter
- Cycle Tracks GPS
- Run the Map